# Retrieve all emails from gmail several times on android app

Tags: java, android, gmail-imap

This can be silly questions, but....

The code below works perfectly to retrieve all emails from gmail. However, after running the app once, gmail sets "Status: POP is enabled for all mail that has arrived since EXECUTION_APP_TIME" in its "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" settings and the app stops getting the old messages (that makes sense).

I need to get all messages from gmail every time I execute the app, but it only works once. Than I need to change the configuration in "Forwarding and POP/IMAP" to "Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)"  in my gmail after every single execution.

Does anyone know how I could sort it out?
  Is there any way to set it automatically through code.

Here is the source code:

```
public void connect(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.pop3.host" , "pop.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.pop3.user" , username);
    // Start SSL connection
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory" , 995 );
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class" , "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" );
    props.put("mail.pop3.port" , 995);

    Log.e("asdasd", "teste");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props , new Authenticator() {
        @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication( username , password);
                }
    });
    try {
        Store store  = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect("pop.gmail.com", 995 , username , password);
        Folder fldr = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        fldr.open(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);

        int totalMsg = fldr.getMessageCount();
        int unread = fldr.getUnreadMessageCount();
        System.out.println("Total MSG: " + totalMsg + " unreaed: " + unread  );

        Message[] messages = fldr.getMessages();
        //Message[] msg = fldr.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
        Message[] msg = messages;

        System.out.print("size " + messages .length);
        if (messages.length == 0) System.out.println("No messages found.");

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Subject : " + messages[i].getSubject());

            if(messages[i].getSubject().equals("test223")){
                System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("From : " + messages[i].getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Subject : " + messages[i].getSubject());
                Object content = messages[i].getContent();

                if (content instanceof String)  
                    System.out.print((String)content);  
                /* text/plain = String
                 * multipart" = Multipart
                 * MimeMessage
                 * input stream = Unknown Data Handler 
                 */                 

                Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msg[i].getContent();

                for (int x = 0; x < multipart.getCount()-1; x++) {
                    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(x);

                    String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

                    if (disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT))) {
                        System.out.println("Mail have some attachment : ");

                        DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                        System.out.println("file name : " + handler.getName());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(bodyPart.getContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fldr.close(true);
        store.close();


    } catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc + " error");
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you store the emails locally instead of fetching them each time?  If you did that, you should consider encrypting them.  It seems like Google might be trying to tell you something.

Comment: @Jessemon thanks...I will do it, but I thought there was faster solution because it is only for a quick demo.